# Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa"

Tags: android, dependencies, androidx, android-multidex

i am unable to resolve this error

Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.birthday.photoframe.birthday_frames.birthday_cake-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.birthday.photoframe.birthday_frames.birthday_cake-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/l

here is my build.gradle file

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.birthday.photoframe.birthday_frames.birthday_cake"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true //addded
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
  optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   } }

   dependencies {

implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.0'

implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this dependency to your gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

Also you should use the same versions for the support and play services libraries. And you should avoid using "+" for latest version.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1'
```

EDIT: You may also add this part to your app level gradle file and try again. I did not see anyone tried this but it may work.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
       //...
    }

    subprojects {
        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                    details.useVersion "12.0.1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2ND UPDATE: Just seen this, the dependency below, covers all the others, then it may cause a duplication issue. Remove the other dependencies and leave this one:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
```